# Guardar arreglo en archivo .txt en C

Tags: c

Quiero escribir una matriz en un archivo .txt pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. Mi código escribe la matriz pero en forma lineal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int arreglo[3][3] = {{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};
int largo = 3;
FILE *fichero;
fichero = fopen("arreglo.txt","w+");
fwrite(arreglo, sizeof(char), sizeof(arreglo), fichero );
fclose(fichero);
return 0;
}
```

Lo que me escribe este código es:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Pero necesito que este así:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

No se si debo usar otra funcíon además de fwrite() para el salto de línea "\n" intente con dos ciclos for pero no me resulta. Es una pregunta básica pero estoy perdido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un simple `for( )`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ){
  const char EndOfLine[] = "\n";
  char arreglo[3][3] = { { '1', '2', '3' },{ '4', '5', '6'}, { '7', '8', '9' } };
  FILE *fichero;

  fichero = fopen( "arreglo.txt", "w+" );

  for( int idx = 0; idx < ( sizeof( arreglo ) / sizeof( arreglo[1] ) ); ++idx ) {
    fwrite( arreglo[idx], sizeof( char ), sizeof( arreglo[0] ), fichero );
    fwrite( EndOfLine, sizeof( EndOfLine ) - 1 , 1, fichero );
  }

  fclose( fichero );

  return 0;
}
```

Simplemente, guardamos de *fila* en *fila*, y colocamos un salto de línea después.

Verás que he cambiado tu `arreglo`; ha pasado de ser `int` a `char`, con lo cual los datos se muestran correctamente, sin caracteres *extraños* entre ellos.

Como nota final, si estás en Windows, se utiliza como *fin de línea* la cadena `"\r\n"`. Deberías de cambiar el valor de `EndOfLine`.